# How to get two values from p:selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I would like to get two values from a p:selectOneMenu.

Here the code:

```
        <p:selectOneMenu 
        id="ip1" value="#{loginBean.f_selectedProject}" rendered="#{loginBean.f_prjType == 'project'}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="dummy"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{loginBean.f_prjListComplete}" var="prj" itemLabel="#{prj.projectDesc}" itemValue="#{prj.projectCd}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

I need to get prj.projectCd and prj.projectDesc values.

Thanks,
Giuseppe

Comment: BalusC the question is different.

Comment: When you select an item from f_prjListComplete, selected item is stored in f_selectedItem in your LoginBean. You should access to its properties using f_selectedItem.getProjectCd() and f_selectedItem.getProjectDesc() if you defined getters properly. Exactly same as marked reference to duplicated item.

Comment: But the value is written to the variable "f_selectedProject", right? So, how I can write two values into two different variables?

Comment: Make one <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{loginBean.myChangeMethod()}" /> inside <p:selectOneMenu/>. That method will be invoked every time when you select item. In that method you can do everything you want with f_selectedItem. Make two variables and set f_selectedItem.getProjectCd() and f_selectedItem.getProjectDesc() to them if that is what you want. Hope that helps..

Comment: Ok, i understood. I try. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why don't you save whole `Project` object to a backing bean?

Comment: @peterremec you are right. I did not see itemValue="#{prj.projectCd}"/> part.